# Create an IEnumerable<Interface> from a bunch of ICollection<Implementation> 's in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, interface, casting

I have a class that is composed of many collections like so:

```
public virtual ICollection<C> CStuff { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<D> DStuff { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<E> EStuff { get; set; }
```

Each of the types implement a common interface.

```
public class C : IStuff {}
public class D : IStuff {}
public class E : IStuff {}
```

I would like to create a collection of all the IStuff in my class, like so:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IStuff>> AllStuffCollections 
{
    get { /* how??? */ }
}

public IEnumerable<IStuff> AllStuff 
{ 
   get 
   { 
       foreach (IEnumerable<IStuff> stuffCollection in AllStuffCollections) 
       {
           foreach (IStuff stuff in stuffCollection) 
           {
               yield return stuff;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this (reflection's OK) without adding each collection explicitly? As in, I don't want to do this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IStuff>> AllStuffCollections 
{
    get 
    { 
        return new List<IEnumerable<IStuff>>() 
        { 
            CStuff.Cast<IStuff>, 
            DStuff.Cast<IStuff>,
            EStuff.Cast<IStuff>
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately this class will be adding more collections of `IStuff` over time and I'm afraid I'll forget to include them in `AllStuffCollections` when it changes.

Additionally the collections themselves are lazy (EF-populated) so I don't want to do anything that would force an immediate "query all the things" to happen.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you _do_ want (even if it's not valid).  I'm not sure if you'd rather use reflection that add the collection explicitly, or if you want to just have the program _know_ that you have three collections somehow.

Comment: [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @Mephy **without adding each collection explicitly !**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If reflection is OK and you don't mind its performance, you can implement it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IStuff>> GetStuffCollections()
{
    var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Type pt = property.PropertyType;
        if (pt.IsGenericType
            && pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
            && typeof(IStuff).IsAssignableFrom(pt.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        {
            yield return (IEnumerable<IStuff>)property.GetValue(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Not only does this solve the problem out of the box (my tests still pass!) but it gives me a Rosetta Stone for using reflection with generics going forward.